# 24 volt Windows PC with built in screen

Tags: pc, portable

Looking to mount a screen with built-in PC for my car.

Requirements:

- Able to run Windows
- WIFI
- Can run on 24 volts power supply from the car
- Able to sustain minor temporary voltage fluctuations

Touch is not a requirement.

Comment: What is the dimensions of the screen you are looking for? What about the ideal resolution? What are you planning on using  the computer for? I am guessing music and movies, but I want to be sure of the requirements.

Comment: Resolution should be HD 1280x720 and up. Size is less important. I'm going to use it for a research project for a business idea - a proof of concept.

Comment: Pretty much any All-in-one computer, or tablet would meet your needs. Most portable computers are already in DC, so you should not have any problems with using the car as a power supply. In fact, there are DC to AC converters in which you can plug laptop chargers into which, invariably, convert the AC back into DC for the laptop's battery.

Comment: How much CPU Mhz do you need?  The Raspberry Pi 3 runs on 5v, and is a complete ARM computer.  There is a special Windows IoT version for this device.  Even has a HDMI port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this one is 12V.  Put a voltage regulator, and a couple capacitors and your all set.

You can pretty much add any screen to this.
1x HDMI
2x miniDP++ connectors

[https://www.amazon.com/Portable-Monitor-Powered-Ultralight-Speakers/dp/B01M7RMBV9/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1514608062&sr=1-1-spons&keywords=Gechic+1503H&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M7RMBV9)

https://www.ebay.com/itm/12-IPS-LED-HDMI-DVI-VGA-Audio-1920x1080-Monitor-for-Raspberry-Pi-PS3-4-Xbox360-/381614017851?_trksid=p2385738.m4383.l4275.c10

[https://www.amazon.com/GeChic-2501H-1920x1080-Portable-Monitor/dp/B018DXABEU/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1514608008&sr=1-1&keywords=hdmi+display+for+raspberry+pi&refinements=p_n_feature_keywords_two_browse-bin%3A6570747011](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018DXABEU)

The UDOO X86 ADVANCED PLUS probably be just as good as the ultra.

https://shop.udoo.org/usa/x86/udoo-x86-ultra.html
[image: mini computer]

Has Wifi/Bluetooth adapter $17 USD.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of dc-dc powersupplies? This is definitely up your alley.
You can also grab a portable usb monitor, everything else is up to what you want.

Failing that you can also grab an inverter to run a regular old plug to your pc. Just be careful not to drain your battery completely. Lower power use is better!